# MailChimp for WooCommerce: Add the checkbox in the middle of the checkout fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, mailchimp

The [MailChimp for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mailchimp-for-woocommerce/) plugin is great, but I've just been given a design where the **'Subscribe to our newsletter'** checkbox in the WooCommerce checkout is immediately after the email field rather than at the bottom of a particular section:

[image: WooCommerce checkout page showing the first name, last name & email fields, immediately followed by MailChimp's sign-up checkbox]

The plugin allows you to type in an action hook for where you'd like the checkbox to appear; for example `woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details`, `woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form`, etc. which allows you to put the checkbox before or after a certain *section* (as long as there's a hook for it), but not in amongst the various fields.

Is there a way to add the MailChimp checkbox to very specific point before or after a certain field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The checkout fields are outputted within a loop, which uses the `woocommerce_form_field()` function to echo out each field:

```
$fields = $checkout->get_checkout_fields( 'billing' );

foreach ( $fields as $key => $field ) {
    woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $checkout->get_value( $key ) );
}
```

this function has a number of *filters* for each specific field type (e.g. `woocommerce_form_field_email`), but no *action* hooks.

However, you can use one of these filters and just a little trickery to add your own hooks:

```
///
//  Add MailChimp checkbox after email field
///

function vnm_mc_after_email_field($field, $key, $args, $value) {
    ob_start();

    do_action('vnm_before_email_field');

    echo $field;

    do_action('vnm_after_email_field');

    return ob_get_clean();
}

add_filter('woocommerce_form_field_email', 'vnm_mc_after_email_field', 10, 4);
```

Since a WordPress filter always has to return a version of the first parameter sent to it (in this case `$field`), all we do is open the output buffer, add our own actions for before and after the field (`vnm_before_email_field`, `vnm_after_email_field`), and then return the output buffer.

Then, in the MailChimp plugin settings under **WooCommerce->MailChimp->Audience**, just add the hook you've just created for your field:

[image: MailChimp plugin settings: opt-in checkbox position, with the new vnm_before_email_field action entered]

...and **done**. Note you could in fact add action hooks around *every* WooCommerce checkout field if you wanted, just by adding the following (untested):

```
///
//  Add `before` & `after` actions around every WooCommerce checkout field
///

function vnm_wc_form_field_actions($field, $key, $args, $value) {
    ob_start();

    do_action('vnm_before_' . $args['type'] . '_field');

    echo $field;

    do_action('vnm_after_' . $args['type'] . '_field');

    return ob_get_clean();
}

add_filter('woocommerce_form_field', 'vnm_wc_form_field_actions', 10, 4);
```